# How to change color in TemplateField using Eval

Tags: asp.net, html, css, gridview

I have a Gridview contain many TemplateField.
I want make every `<td>` in my html source equal the color saved in my database 
I try code Located below but not working it's  give me a `<span>` tag inside `<td>` with my color but **But do not appear on the browser**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BackGround Color">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label  ID="lblBackColor" runat="server" 
                   BackColor='<%# ConvertFromHexToColor( Eval("BackColor").ToString()) %>'>
            </asp:Label>
           <itemstyle width="20%" horizontalalign="Center" />
     </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code working

```
public  Color ConvertFromHexToColor(string hex)
{
    string colorcode = hex;
    int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
    return clr;
}
```

And this is the source  html and css code in my browser

```
            <td>
                <span id="BodyZone__ThemesGrid_lblForeColor_0"  style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></span>
                <itemstyle width="20%" horizontalalign="Center">
                    </itemstyle>
            </td>
```

CSS

```
table.activity_datatable td {
padding: 8px 15px;
color: #6c6c6c;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: there is no text in span so there is no color in the backgroupnd

Comment: what do you mean by **every td**

Comment: <td> is the standard table data tag in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place text inside of your Label (which renders to a span)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BackGround Color">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label  ID="lblBackColor" runat="server" BackColor='<%# ConvertFromHexToColor( Eval("BackColor").ToString()) %>'>PUT_TEXT_HERE</asp:Label>
    <itemstyle width="20%" horizontalalign="Center" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You may also prefer using a Panel (which renders to a div) rather than a Label. Don't forget to put stuff inside of the div or span.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check with a boolean value if it is true then Green colour else Red colour will effect. Then displaying text with the respective colour according to the Eval function. Here GetStatus is a method you need to create it in code behind with its we are binding the text to UI, or else you can bind with Eval or Bind function as usual.

```
 ForeColor='<%# (bool)Eval("UserType")==true?System.Drawing.Color.Green:System.Drawing.Color.Red %>'
                                Text='<%# GetStatus((bool)Eval("UserType")) %>'>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ForeColor='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ESM")) == "Elective" ? System.Drawing.Color.Green: 
           Convert.ToString(Eval("ESM")) == "Emergency" ? System.Drawing.Color.Red: System.Drawing.Color.Purple%>'
```

Try this code..........